# ADB - No device found

Tags: android, usb, device-driver

While attempting to create an apk file in Unity, I encountered the below error. I'm running a Windows 8 PC with a brand new Huawei Honor 8 cell phone connected by USB to the computer. Connecting my older Nexus 4 android phone has the same result:
[image: Unity]

My PC's operating system was able to find the device, and the drivers appear to be up-to-date in the device manager:
[image: DeviceMgr]

However, running `adb devices` from the command prompt reveals nothing could be found. I also tried restarting the adb server: 
[image]

Nothing appears in Chrome either:
[image]

I attempted other connection types in the device itself (PTP, MTP, Charge only, etc), but this had no affect on the problem, even after disconnecting and reconnecting the phone's USB cable to the computer:

[image]

I've got JDK installed and Android SDK. In the SDK manager my installed files look like this:
[image]

I also checked that the USB driver is installed in the manager:
[image]

At this point I have no idea what I'm missing, it's probably  something simple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you enabled developer options on your phone and ensured that USB debugging is turned on?

Comment: On my own Huawei P10, I needed to set _Always prompt when connecting to USB_ option to ON to be able to debug with my phone.

Comment: Turns out USB debugging was *not* set to enabled like I thought, this was the whole problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and I resolved it by checking my Player Settings (Edit -> Project Settings -> Player) and ensuring that the Minimum API Level was at or below my phone's Android version.